# How to delay an observable subscription to finish method execution from first observable

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

In my angular2 app i want to execute observable subscriptions in sequence but i get error because 1st subscription has a method which i think takes a lot of time. I have services for different components so that they cache my data and available to all components. I am new to Http Observables and dont know the sequence in which they execute.

**PriceList.service.ts**

```
export class PriceListService
{
    private priceLists : PriceList[];
    private observable : Observable<any>;
    public getAll()
    {
        if(this.priceLists)
        {
            return Observable.of(this.priceLists);
        }
        else if (this.observable)
        {
            return this.observable;
        }
        else
        {
            this.observable = this.authHttp.get(this.appService.getApiUrl() + "api/price-list/list")
                .map(response => {
                    this.observable = null;
                    if(response.status == 400)
                    {
                        return "Failure";
                    }
                    else if(response.status == 200)
                    {
                        let myJson = response.json();
                        this.priceLists = myJson.data.priceList;
                        return this.priceLists;
                    }
                })
                .share();
            return this.observable;
        }
    }
}
```

**Product.service.ts**

```
export class ProductService
{
    products : Product[];
    observable : Observable<any>;
    priceLists : any;
    priceListMap : Map<number, any> = new Map<number, any>();
    defaultPriceList : Map<number, any> = new Map<number, any>();
    productMap : Map<number , any> = new Map<number , any>();
    defaultPriceListId : number;
    public getActiveProducts()
    {
        if(this.products)
        {
            return Observable.of(this.products);
        }
        else if (this.observable)
        {
            return this.observable;
        }
        else
        {
            this.observable = this.authHttp.get(this.appService.getApiUrl() + "api/product/list/active")
                .map(response => {
                    this.observable = null;
                    if(response.status == 400)
                    {
                        return "Failure";
                    }
                    else if(response.status == 200)
                    {
                        let myJson = response.json();
                        this.products = myJson.data.products;
                        this.getPriceLists();
                        return this.products;
                    }
                })
                .share();
            return this.observable;
        }
    }
    getPriceLists()
    {
        this.priceListService.getAll().subscribe(
            success => { this.priceLists = success; },
            error => {},
            ()=> { this.populatePriceListMap(); }
        );
    }
    populatePriceListMap()
    {
        for(let priceList of this.priceLists)
        {
            for(let product of this.products)
            {
                for(let prices of product.prices)
                {
                    if(priceList.id == prices.priceList.id)
                    {
                        this.productMap.set(product.id , {price : prices.price , discount : prices.discount});
                    }
                }
            }
            if(priceList.isDefault == 1)
            {
                this.defaultPriceList.set(priceList.id , this.productMap);
                this.defaultPriceListId = priceList.id;
            }
            this.priceListMap.set(priceList.id , this.productMap);
            this.productMap = new Map<number , any>();
        }
    }
    getDefaultList()
    {
        if(this.defaultPriceList){
            return Observable.of(this.defaultPriceList.get(this.defaultPriceListId));
        }
    }
}
```

**ListProduct.component.ts**

```
export class ListProductsComponent implements OnInit
{
    products:any = null;
    pricesMap : Map<number, any> = new Map<number, any>();
    prices:any = [];
    discounts:any = [];
    ngOnInit()
    { 
        this.productService.getActiveProducts().subscribe(
            success =>{
                this.products = success;
            },
            error =>{},
            () =>{
                this.populatePrices();
            }
        );
    }
    populatePrices()
    {
        this.productService.getDefaultList().subscribe(
            success =>
            {
                this.pricesMap = success;
            },
            error =>{},
            ()=>{
                for (let product of this.products)
                {
                    let myObject = this.pricesMap.get(product.id);
                    this.prices[product.id] = myObject.price;
                    this.discounts[product.id] = myObject.discount;
                }
            }
        );
    }
}
```

**Error**

[image: error]

**What it should do**

I want my component to execute functions in this order.

1. I want to execute `getActiveProducts()` so that my `productService` fetches products from api and stores them.
2. I want to execute `getPriceLists()` of `productService` to fetch data from other service and store that in `productService`.
3. I want to execute `populatePriceListMap()` so that it populates different properties of service.
4. I want to execute `populatePrices()` in my component and assign values to different properties.

**Problem i am facing**

I think it executes step 1 and 4 while step 1 is doing its work. I want to display the properties being set in step 4 but it does not assign them and gives error.

Answer (score 0):

You're setting this `pricesMap` variable in the `onNext` callback in subscribe, and then accessing it in the `onCompleted` callback.
You're obviously setting it to an undefined value which comes in through as a value. That's the error.

As for best practices, you might want to look at how to do Rx, [in an Rx-like way](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJSKoans).

Answer (score 0):

If you can make both get calls **in parallel** (one call does not depend on the other, just the results need to be synched), then I would recommend using the `forkJoin` operator. It's to handle parallel calls where it waits until they're all complete before it pumps the results for each.

For example:
**EDIT:** Had a mistake previously: I put take(2) for the second observable when it should have also been to take(1)

```
var obs1 = this.authHttp.get(firstUrl).take(1);
var obs2 = this.authHttp.get(secondUrl).take(1);
Observable.forkJoin(obs1, obs2)
          .subscribe(responseArray => {
               // Do something 
               // where responseArray[0] is the response you receive from the first get call, obs1
               // responseArray[1] is the response you receive from the second get call, obs2
          });
```

You can read more about it here: https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/forkjoin.md

But, if you want to run them **sequentially** (the second get call needs parameters from the first get's response), then you're looking for the switchMap operator. So using the same obs1 and obs2 above, you'd want to do:

```
obs1.do(resp1 => {
       // Anything you want to do with the first response before you fire off the second one
  }).switchMap(obs2)
    .subscribe(resp2 => {
               // Do something 
    });
```